# Using cin.get() to discard unwanted characters from the input stream in c++

Tags: c++, cin

I am working on an assignment for my C++ class. The following code is given. The directions explain to enter a six character string and observe the results. When I do this, the second user prompt is passed over and the program ends. I am pretty certain the reason for this is that the first cin.getline() is leaving the extra character(s) in the input stream which is messing up the second cin.getline() occurrence. I am to use cin.get, a loop, or both to prevent the extra string characters from interfering with the second cin.getline() function.

Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char buffer[6];
   cout << "Enter five character string: ";
   cin.getline(buffer, 6);
   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "The string you entered was " << buffer << endl;
   cout << "Enter another five character string: ";
   cin.getline(buffer, 6);
   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "The string you entered was " << buffer << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The newline character stays in the input buffer after the first input.

After the first read try to insert:

```
cin.ignore(); // to ignore the newline character
```

or better still:

```
//discards all input in the standard input stream up to and including the first newline.
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You will have to `#include <limits>` header for this.

EDIT:
Although using std::string would be much better, following modified code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char buffer[6];
   cout << "Enter five character string: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cin.get(buffer[i]);
   buffer[5] = '\0';
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "The string you entered was " << buffer << endl;

   cout << "Enter another five character string: ";
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cin.get(buffer[i]);
   buffer[5] = '\0';
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   cout << endl << endl;
   cout << "The string you entered was " << buffer << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your response. Its still skipping over the second cin.get() occurrence though with cin.ignore as well as your second suggestion. I'm not sure if its just the new line character that needs to be ignored. For example, if I enter "abcdef" with the first cin.getline() function, it displays "abcde"(the last index holding the null character, of course) but "f" is still in the input buffer. I need a way to discard runover characters in the event the user enters a string larger than 5 characters.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I have been banging my head off my computer desk for hours on this.If it's not too much trouble, could you talk me through the arguments you used in cin.ignore(). I understand the for loops being used instead of the cin.getline() function, but I'm not familiar with the <limit> library functions. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: numeric_limits<streamsize>::max() is a built-in constant for maximum size of input stream possible in C++. cin.ignore(someInt,someChar) ignores characters upto a maximum of someInt characters or until the delimiting someChar character is reached, in this case the newline character.

Comment: Why don't you ignore twice if you insert endl twice?